# How to add some minutes to a Date format

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working with the Google Calendar API and because the required  date format I´m using the next way to get the starting time:

```
   const date1 = (mail._doc.Data[1].Date + 'T' + mail._doc.Data[1].Time )
   const startingTime = new Date (date1)
```

This works and give me the next input that allows me to create the event in the calendar if I manually set the ending time

```
2022-07-15T21:23:00.000Z
```

That starting time will change depending of data in the server. For the ending time I would like for it to be the starting time (whatever it is) plus 45 minutes but I cant make it work.

Comment: dates have two methods you can use to help ... getMinutes/setMinutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use timestamp in `getTime()` and use this formula to extend the current timestamp

```
45 minutes x 60 seconds x 1000 miliseconds
```

```js
const startTime = new Date() //your starting time

console.log(startTime)

const startTimestamp = startTime.getTime()

//45 minutes x 60 seconds x 1000 miliseconds
const timeExtent = 45*60*1000

const endTime = new Date(startTimestamp + timeExtent)

console.log(endTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const date = new Date();
console.log('Before : ' + date);
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 45); //adding 45 minutes
console.log('After : ' + date);
```